# Partition a positive definite square matrix into two identical matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix, decomposition

simply I want to partition a `n*n` positive definite matrix into an identical `n*r` matrix B where r is arbitrary, in the other word:

```
B*B^T=A
(n*r)*(n*r)^T=(n*n)
```

Edit:
I think it was my fault ill-describing my problem.
let `B` be a matrix with dimension `(n*r)`.
give it to a function `A=f(B^T*B)` where A is `(n*n)`.
I know that this function will keep the rank of matrix, in the other word `rank(A)=rank(B'*B)`.
now i want to extract new `B`. so the new `B` has `(n*r)` again.

Comment: "lower dimension" "r is arbitrary" - r is not arbitrary according to your title; r<=n

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose that you have the following example:

```
n = 4;
rng(0)
A = rand(n,n);
B = A * A';
```

If the matrix `B` is full rank, you can not exactly cover the original matrix using fewer dimensions. So, you can only *approximate* it. The key idea here is to minimize the reconstruction error.

You can decompose `B` into its eigenvectors using [eigenvalue decomposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigendecomposition_of_a_matrix). You can use [`eig`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/eig.html) in MATLAB, but you need to sort the eigenvalues and corresponding eigenvectors afterwards. Instead, I prefer [Singular Value Decomposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition) and use [`svd`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/svd.html) in MATLAB. Note that SVD gives the optimal solution for the reconstruction error in low-rank matrix approximation.

```
[U,S,~] = svd(B);
U = U * sqrt(S);
```

We know that `B = U * U'` now. See relation between SVD and eigenvalue decomposition [here](http://linneus20.ethz.ch:8080/2_2_1.html).

As I stated, we need to approximate it. I choose the dimensions covering 99% of the total variance as follows:

```
coverage =  cumsum(diag(S.^2));
coverage = coverage ./ norm(S,'fro')^2;
[~, nEig] = max(coverage > 0.99);
U2 = U(:,1:nEig);
```

U2 has 2 columns instead of 4 in this case. If the data is correlated, the gain will be even less. The results are as follows:

```
B
B1 = U*U'
B2 = U2*U2'

B =

    2.8966    2.1881    1.1965    2.1551
    2.1881    1.9966    0.6827    1.8861
    1.1965    0.6827    0.7590    0.5348
    2.1551    1.8861    0.5348    2.0955


B1 =

    2.8966    2.1881    1.1965    2.1551
    2.1881    1.9966    0.6827    1.8861
    1.1965    0.6827    0.7590    0.5348
    2.1551    1.8861    0.5348    2.0955


B2 =

    2.8896    2.2134    1.1966    2.1385
    2.2134    1.9018    0.6836    1.9495
    1.1966    0.6836    0.7586    0.5339
    2.1385    1.9495    0.5339    2.0528
```

That seems to be a good approximation.

Comment: well that was a great answer, but as i said, i need to have arbitrary r, this solution will give me r=4 always.

Comment: No, it gives you the one you need. Check the dimensions of `U2`. `nEig` is the one you need to change. If you like, you can manually set it.

Comment: sorry for miss-understanding petrichor.

Comment: well because in iterations the value of r increases. now im stuck when r gets bigger than n. even if there is a proof that it cant be done, i would be glad to know it. sorry that this question became lengthy.

Comment: Oh, I'm  not aware of the methods when r increases :(

Comment: it ok, thanks so much petrichor for your time. i greatly appreciate it